# Is it okay to accept your own answer?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26205/is-there-an-optimum-time-to-leave-between-writing-and-self-proofreading) a few days ago and since there were no answers decided to research an answer myself (it's not like I have any of my own research or writing to be doing!). I wrote an answer which has received a number of up-votes.

Normally I always try to accept an answer for any question I ask so if I get no other answers on this question is it okay to accept my own answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Yes! Go ahead](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

However, unlike accepting someone else's answer, you must wait 48 hours from when you asked the question, the accepted answer won't stick at the top (if there are multiple answers), and you won't earn reputation for accepting it. ([Source](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/))